# Submit Form Without Refresh -- and actually submit it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a form and load data based on the form submission in AJAX and PHP. I would like to accomplish this without reloading the page.

**html/php**

```
<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="image1">
  <button type="submit" name="image2">
  <button type="submit" name="image3">
  <button type="submit" name="image4">
</form>

<div>
// content gets loaded into here 
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("div").load("content-load.php");
}
```

**content-load.php**

```
$validInputs = array('image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4');

foreach ($validInputs as $v) {
  if(isset($_POST[$v])){
    // load content associated with image1, or image2, etc, into Div
   }
 }
```

Yes, the "event.preventDefault()" is a nice solution to prevent page refresh. However it doesn't actually submit the form! I need the form to be submitted, because the content I am loading into Div is dependent on "$_POST[$v]" being set. Depending on whether the user clicks the first, second, third, or fourth submit button, the content-load.php will loop through $validInputs and determine which button was pressed. Depending on which button was clicked, specific content will be loaded.

If I use ajax and prevent default, the above will never run because the form is being prevented from submitted. The php needs to loop through the array and determine which button was pressed -- but no button was pressed because of event.preventDefault! How do I get php to detect which button was "set" without using page refresh?

Comment: In order to submit the form you will need to use jQuery's `.ajax()` or `.post()` functions. `.load()` is a weak version of AJAX that primarily acts as a request to the server to return some information. [Here are some basics.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) In addition, you may want to look at some basic form setup in HTML. Having multiple submits, as you are doing, is not particularly valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `event.preventDefault();` inside handler it cancels the form submit action. If you want to submit the form without page refresh better way is to use `$.ajax` and `$("div").load("content-load.php");` should be put in success callback.

Comment: This will actually submit the form? I thought .load was just a "minified" version of $.ajax

Comment: No this will not submit the form. You can make a post request with necessary parameter with $.ajax. Because the moment we are submitting the form page refresh is bound to happen unless you use some hacky way to prevent that with form target attribute with hidden iframe, which will then make things complecated

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jquery, than the the $.post is your friend.

Example:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
$( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Further reading: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/